# How to I fill the central 95% confidence interval of a matplotlib histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, fill

I am able to make a matplotlib histogram no problem. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to use something like `fillbetween` to change the fill color of the central 95% CI of my data.

I can only get `fillbetween` to work when if I use a trick with a numpy histogram and bincenters. i.e.:

````
bins = np.linspace(-a.max(),a.max(),400)
hist = np.histogram(a,bins = bins)[0]
bincenters = 0.5*(bins[1:] + bins[:-1])

b = plt.plot(bincenters,hist, linestyle = 'None')
plt.fill_between(bincenters,hist, color = '#7f7f7f')

plt.fill_between(bincenters, hist, interpolate=False,
                where=((bincenters>=lower_p) & (bincenters<=upper_p)), hatch = '...', facecolor = '#7f7f7f')```


Here's my existing code that I'd rather use to create the matplotlib histogram (which I think looks better) with some extras plotting on top: 

#Create Histogram
axes[1] = boota.plot.hist(ax = axes[1],bins = 50, legend = None, histtype = 'bar', color = '#7f7f7f')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Spatial Decay Rate (α)', size = 16, fontweight = 'bold')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Frequency', labelpad = 11, size = 16, fontweight = 'bold')

#Ticklabels 
axes[0].tick_params(labelsize = 14)
axes[1].tick_params(labelsize = 14)

#draw vertical line at remote powerlaw (rem_a)
rem_a = 0.649
axes[1].axvline(x=rem_a, color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1.5, label='remote decay \nrate $α_r$ = 0.649')
legend = axes[1].legend(ncol = 1, loc = 'upper left', fontsize='large')
legend.draw_frame(False)

at2 = AnchoredText("B",prop=dict(size=20), loc='upper right',frameon=False)
axes[1].add_artist(at2)
````

Comment: Would be great to get a figure showing the output of this since I have no idea what it looks like by just reading the code, although I can somewhat guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`fill_betweenx`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_betweenx) which I think is better fit here

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

arr = np.random.normal(size=500)
ci = norm(*norm.fit(arr)).interval(0.95)  # fit a normal distribution and get 95% c.i.
height, bins, patches = plt.hist(arr, alpha=0.3)
plt.fill_betweenx([0, height.max()], ci[0], ci[1], color='g', alpha=0.1)  # Mark between 0 and the highest bar in the histogram
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks CT Zhu. This will work, but it's not quite as visually pleasing as only filling the bars themselves. Especially since I will have some other lines and text on the plot. Any other ideas?

Comment: @celder88 what are you going to do if c.i. do not fall right on the bin edges?

Comment: CT Zhu, you are right again. I ended up using your suggestion with a hatch edgecolor = white and no facecolor. This way, the hatches were only visible where they overlapped with the histogram and the background is clear. Thanks again for your advice.